# I want to learn the Indian flute (Bansuri). Is there any site where I can learn how to play this instrument?

Tags: learning, classical-music, self-learning, flute, indian-classical

Recently I started listening Indian classical music and I love the music of the Bansuri, an Indian flute. I want to learn how to play it. Do you know of any site where I can learn the Indian flute? I don't play any musical instruments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as because website recommendations are off-topic here; see http://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic